# Yii The view file does not exist - where do mail layouts go

Tags: yii, yii2

I am using basic template but have adapted the advanced user password reset functionality, for some reason I can't get it to find the mail layouts.

So in `\mail\layouts` I have 
- passwordResetToken-html.php
- passwordResteToken-text.php

In web.php I have

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => 'app\mail\layouts',
...
```

The advanced template uses

```
'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
```

But as i'm using basic template, its not in the common/mail folder.

In sendMail function in PasswordResetRequestForm.php i have

```
return \Yii::$app->mailer->compose(['html' => 'passwordResetToken-html',     'text' => 'passwordResetToken-text'], ['user' => $user]) 
...
```

However getting error
The view file does not exist: app\mail\layouts\passwordResetToken-html.php

I know this is going to be something small but for the life of me i cannot see it

Comment: Try using `'@app\mail\layouts\'`

Comment: tried it but got `Invalid path alias: @app\mail\layouts`

Answer (score 1):

Removed the 'viewPath' of config, as the [doc](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/pt-br/tutorial-mailing) don't use it. 
So it works.